# Colours in syntax highlighting

Tags: discussion, design, syntax-highlighting

As mentioned in the comments to [this answer on meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/872/text-immediate-following-double-backslashes-is-highlighted-as-macro-inside-a-code/874#874), Martin's improved syntax highlighting is installed now. Somehow it happened that not the most recent version got installed (or it didn't get installed *as is*). The effect is that `\def`, `\newcommand` and friends get a colour doesn't fit into our design.

Thus my question: Do we want an extra colour for those commands at all? (I don't.) If yes, maybe Jin can have a look what colour would fit.

Another thing: `$` and `&` also get coloured (which I like), but also this colour is slightly obtrusive in my opinion. Thoughts?

Comment: Ok, now thats wierd. Have a look at [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11113/2975). Some macros which start with `\@...` are highlighted correctly (i.e. fully), but with others only the `\@`. Also in the first mentioning of `\mytitle` it is correct, but the second one only the `\my` is highlighted!! I really have to look into that.

Comment: @Martin: weird indeed. But I can't say anything about it since I don't understand how your script works.

Comment: Ok, got it. That post has some special right-to-left unicode markers in it which confuses the syntax highlighting code. Mystery solved.

Answer (score 6):

In the [latest version posted](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/attachmentText?id=115&aid=8755870892943144368&name=lang-latex.js&token=6213cce870fbc48eaf596afc04164c2b) the syntax highlighted was disabled by commenting the `PR_DECLARATION` line out. Maybe the comments have been removed. I got a little carried away when I added it. I agree, it's not really needed.

The colors are defined completely separate from the highlighter plugin using CSS. The purple color for `\newcommand` and friends is really unpleasant.

The blue colors of the `$` and `&`, but also for `{ }`, `( )` (`PR_PUNCTUATION`) should really be changed to something more fitting to the page.
I think *brown* or *red*-ish colors are more suitable.

Comment: I'd say: Let wait a day or two for other opinions and then ask Jin if he can have a look for a good colour.

Comment: I'm watching the discussion here for a general consensus before updating the CSS.  I will bring this up with Jin as well on Monday.

Comment: @Geoff: Thanks! There seem to be no other opinions coming in, so maybe you can go ahead and remove the special treatment of `\def`, `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand` and friends, and change that blue color if you got to talk to Jin.

Comment: @Geoff: Is there any new development? What did Jin say?

Comment: @Geoff: Just another _ping_ ...

Answer (score 3):

There are also three related issues I like to list here again for clarity:

1. The units for dimensions are not properly separated, e.g. the `1in` in 
   `\csname#1input\endcsname` is highlighted as a number. I saw this in one of [Herberts posts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2334/include-without-pagebreak/10833#10833). I think I can fix this easily in the related regex.
2. The syntax highlighting in the edit preview is still not working correctly, i.e. set to `default`, which renders `#` as a comment character.
   The [fix](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/851/preview-treats-as-comment/903#903) for this requires a minor change in the HTML code of the site.
3. There is [no syntax highlighting on meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/873/2975) itself.

We could fix these issues (at least 1&2) in one go with the colors in order to bother Geoff Dalgas♦, or whoever is in charge for that, only once.

Comment: @Martin: wild guess on the fist point: it is missing a word-boundary at the end (\b). In case you might be interested, I had a stab at this earlier: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10/syntax-highlighting/773#773

Comment: Thanks @morbusg, I was planning to add a `\b`. Like I said, I just added a fix at the existing one. I have no idea why your version wasn't used in the first place.

Comment: Well, like I said in the earlier anwer, I'm no regex-guru. In hindsight, for instance, my first LITERAL definition  should've been a KEYWORD. I'm glad it all happened though, one way or another `:-)`

Comment: @Martin: It seems that #2 just got implemented. I'm not sure if I want #3.

Comment: @Hendrik: No, `#2` seems to be still not working. It works with the Greacemonkey script I provided, maybe you have this activated?

Comment: @Martin: When I wrote that comment, it seemed to be working, and I didn't even have your script installed on that computer. Now it's not working, indeed.