# Text immediate following double backslashes is highlighted as Macro inside a code block

Tags: bug, status-completed, code, syntax-highlighting

I just saw this at [Herbert answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9893/how-to-rotate-text-in-table-across-column-spanning-many-rows/9895#9895) to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9893/2975):
if a code block contains `\\` directly followed by a text then the syntax highlighting marks it as macro.
This is quite irritating and should be fixed. Most likely the regular expression for macros misses a look-behind instruction.

Another example where the regular expression should be improved, *added by Hendrik:* In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7574/latex-errors-requirepackage-or-loadclass-in-options-section-and-file-arti/7577#7577) it is probably hardly avoidable that `\MikTeX` is interpreted as a control sequence, but at least the `2.9` shouldn't be part of the control sequence. See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9897/1235), where it looks as if `\ifnum0` was the control sequence. Or is this intentional?

**Proposed Solution**

I updated the JavaScript syntax file for LaTeX ([New Version](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/attachmentText?id=115&aid=8755870892943144368&name=lang-latex.js&token=6213cce870fbc48eaf596afc04164c2b)) which now
highlights word with starts with `\` and are followed by a-z, A-Z and `@`
OR followed by any other *single* character (e.g. `\\`, `\_`) as macros.

Here an example result (as slightly magnified image):

[image: Example of new syntax highlighting]

I would ask people to **vote** on this version, so that it can be installed on tex.sx and maybe also on meta. See my answer below for further information and the discussion on the previous versions of the above file.

Comment: Good that you brought this up. I added another similar possible bug; hope that's OK.

Comment: The new version works well. Thank's for the work! Could you please accept your answer (an maybe a mod could tag the question as status-completed).

Comment: @Caramdir, @Hendrik: The [fix for the preview mode](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/851/preview-treats-as-comment/903#903) still needs to be added too.

Comment: @MartinScharrer - If this is resolved, do you mind adding a [meta-tag:status-completed] to the question?

Comment: @Oded: Thanks for pointing this out. Now done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I now modified the mentioned plugin by myself and uploaded it to the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=115).

I changed the regular expressions for macros from

```
[PR.PR_KEYWORD, /^\\[^ \r\n{}\[\]=]+/],
```

to

```
[PR.PR_KEYWORD, /^\\(\\|[^ \r\n{}\[\]=]+)/],
```

so telling the prettifier that `\\` is a macro by itself.

Please update it on tex.se. Thanks!

**Update**

I updated the [plugin as requested](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/attachmentText?id=115&aid=6433373786140659013&name=lang-latex.js&token=1f9ffc82d7e710f9cebb0f190067ff80) with only letters, '@' and also ':' for macros plus single character sequences.

An [additional alternative](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/attachmentText?id=115&aid=3849660016172502405&name=lang-latex.js&token=3346fd68bcd90dfbdd1f46a6183ad23f) also adds special highlighting for declarations and the `$` and `&` characters.

**Update 2**

[Bugfixed version of plugin with extra highlighting](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/attachmentText?id=115&aid=-1166743303320393442&name=lang-latex.js&token=bcc69c563a93e05f35c5dd7026c32dc1) Fixes wrongly highlighted macros which start with `\def` etc.

**Demo version**

I now wrote a small [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) script (a firefox plugin which allow you to run your own JS files on websites you visit) to enable the new syntax highlighting. If someone has interest to try it out, [here is the script](http://www.scharrer-online.de/raw-attachment/wiki/Software/files/new_syntax_highlighting.user.js).
It also works on meta and in addition on inline code tags.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to just allow letters and @ since (usually) everything else terminates the the macro name. And then there should be a separate case for control characters.

Comment: I had the same reaction when I saw the current regex, but the updated version seems to work well enough.

Comment: No, there are still lots of case left where it does the wrong thing. For example `\sin(t)+x` would highlight everything.

Comment: @Caramdir: Good example. You can see it happen in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3622/best-way-to-generate-a-nice-function-graph-in-latex/3630#3630); even the closing dollar gets highlighted there.

Comment: Ok, I see. I can change it to letters, `@` and IMHO also `:` to support LaTeX3 code.

Comment: @Caramdir: I made the suggested changes and uploaded to the issue tracker. Now only letters, `@` and `:` (for LaTeX3 code, can easily be removed if not wanted) build a macro. As a second rule every single character after the backslash is also a macro. I also attached a second proposal with some extra highlights.

Comment: Great! The extra highlights have the problem of matching anything that starts with `\def`. I'm not sure how much of a problem that is though.

Comment: @Caramdir: Thanks, I fixed that now.

Comment: I'm aghast! I thought it used catcodes to work out what to highlight.

Comment: @Martin: I've just tried your script, and it looks good. Only the special treatment of the `\def` s looks strange to me. (And I wouldn't want to have the highlighting in comments, so I'll disable the script again.)

Comment: @Martin: I just see what my problem with the `\def` s is: I think it doesn't fit into the colour design.

Comment: @Hendrik: I don't like the pink color as well. The color could be changed in the CSS file, but it might be just better to not handle `\def` s differently than other macros. Removing that line is simple.

Comment: @Hendrik: I now removed the special handling of definitions again from the greasemonkey script.

Comment: @Martin: Unfortunately I can't give another +1. Maybe you should update your question and ask people to vote on your changes. Or what would be the right way to make this official?

Comment: @Hendrik: I did update the question as you said.

Comment: @Martin: Somehow the special handling of definitions got into the recent build. Maybe you didn't upload it to the issue tracker? Maybe we'll have to discuss it in a separate post? As I already said, it just doesn't fit into our design.

Comment: @Hendrik: The [version I mention in the 'question' above](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/attachmentText?id=115&aid=8755870892943144368&name=lang-latex.js&token=6213cce870fbc48eaf596afc04164c2b) has the special handling disabled, i.e. the corresponding code line is commented out.

Comment: Looking at your rexp's, a `\def\ä{Sup?}\ä` wouldn't get the proper hilight.

Comment: @morbusg: No, it wouldn't. I only fixed some issues in the original version which only had English letters in it. No one requested non-English letters, so I didn't put them in.

Comment: Also, does the unioning take care of the lack of `[^\]` before the comment (`%`) rexp (`\%` is just percent, not comment)?

Comment: @morbusg: The above regexes are outdated. See the 'updates' or the updated question. Yes `\%` is correctly recognized as a macro, not as an comment. AFAIK the parser matches the regexes at the *begin* of the text and then removes the match. This way `something\%` will trigger the `PR_KEYWORD` regex when `\ ` is reached and the `%` is never tested by `PR_COMMENT`.

Comment: @Martin: Strange, so why is it enabled on the main site? Do you have an idea?

Comment: @Hendrik: Maybe the person who installed it removed the comment chars before it.

Comment: @Martin: I think I'll open a new post here on meta tomorrow, asking if we want the special treatment (I don't actually), and asking Jin to look for colours that fit better into the design. (The colour of the `&` also seems slightly obtrusive to me.)

Comment: @Hendrik: That's a good idea. I don't like the color of `&` as well.

Answer (score 4):

We use [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify) with a hint for the Tex language:

`<pre class="lang-tex prettyprint"><code>`

We have implemented TeX prettify highlighting using a user contributed plugin found [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/attachmentText?id=115&aid=7911114425991426027&name=lang-latex.js&token=f0f153280f0fe2c829a7288dff59ccbc).  A previous discussion on how this was done can be found [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/syntax-highlighting).  We have [reported](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=115) this issue so hopefully a contribution will be made that will resolve it soon.

Comment: @Geoff: Could you please update the Prettify plugin to the last version found in that bug report. That offers a vast improvement over the current highlighting.

Comment: @Caramdir I have committed the latest version located on the bug report.  You should see this on the next build.

Comment: @Geoff: Great! .

Answer (score 4):

As I think there are no objections, could someone in charge please add Martin's code to the site. TikZ code still looks horrible.

Comment: I know: this should be a comment and not an answer, but this way the question gets bumped to the top.

Comment: Thanks @Caramdir.

Comment: I guess it's better if you post it as a comment to Jeff's answer, with the comment directed at Geoff.

Comment: @Hendrik: That worked surprisingly well.

Comment: I just pointed you to someone in charge `:-)`