# There is no syntax highlighting on Meta

Tags: feature-request, meta, syntax-highlighting

I just posted, in Meta, a [bug report](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/872/2975) about wrong syntax highlighting on the main site. However, my example code showing the wrong behavior is not very useful because there seems to be no syntax highlighting on Meta itself.
I would like to suggest that it is added for such cases.

Example code which shows status of syntax highlighting on Meta:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Syntax highlighting? \relax 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/168244)

Answer (score 7):

[2 days ago syntax highlighting was turned on on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120812/163868) so to be fair I think it should be turned on here as well.

Comment: No, still (or again?) no syntax highlighting. See the code example in the question.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Syntax highlighting? \relax 
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ccc}
    a&b\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Syntax highlighting? \relax 
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ccc}
    a&b\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You can force syntax highlighting by prefixing the block with `<!-- language: lang-latex -->`  as in the second block here, although the styling is so slight it's hard to see the difference but if you view the source of the generated hml in your browser you see the first starts

`<code>\documentclass{article}`

and the second starts

`<code><span class="kwd">\documentclass</span><span class="pun">{</span><span class="pln">article</span><span class="pun">}</span><span class="pln">`

Comment: you are holding a trident aren't you ;)

Comment: Same language keys also work with github-like code blocks. I don't know how to input this in a comment, so please see my deleted answer.